# Minification Angular JS ends up with angular.XX function is undefined

Tags: angularjs, minify

I needed to modify my angular app for minification purposes.

So, I converted all code segments from this

```
app.run(function($cordovaVibration, $cordovaMedia, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSplashscreen) {
```

to this

```
app.run(['$cordovaVibration', '$cordovaMedia', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaSplashscreen',function($cordovaVibration, $cordovaMedia, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSplashscreen) {
```

And I verified the new version by running it and it just run fine.

But when I did the modification, I saw it bombed at this next line

```
var Ha, I, Ta=!1, n = angular.Ha("myApp", ["ionic", "ngCordova"]);
```

And the error is this:

```
TypeError: angular.Ha is not a function. (In 'angular.Ha("myApp",["ionic","ngCordova"])', 'angular.Ha' is undefined)
```

What do we do now?

Comment: who did you minify your code ?

Comment: Get rid of the `app` variable and always use `angular.module()`

Comment: Have you tried a linter such as http://www.jslint.com/? Might find something that way that should be cleaned up.

Comment: Alainib, it was http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home.

Comment: charlietfl, how do I convert this code to one that does not use the app variable? `app.run(function($cordovaVibration, $cordovaMedia) {})`

Comment: BrianS, I did not use a jslinter. It is a great suggestion though. But I think if I follow Charlieftl's approach, this weird error should go away. I am just not familiar with that syntax though.

Answer (score 0):

Per Alainib's comment, I just casted some doubt over the minificator I was using (*which is http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home*) and switched to *http://JSCompress.com* instead.

And the error is gone!

The bottom line is there was nothing wrong with the code to begin with. 
It was the minificator that wasted a nice afternoon of mine.